# Why is jTDS failing to convert SQL Server datetime to java.sql.Timestamp?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, jtds

Here's my mapping.

```
@Column(name = "someDateTime") // which is `datetime` in SQL Server table
public java.sql.Timestamp getSomeDateTime() {
    return someDateTime;
}

URL is spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myUrl:1433/bizproj;socketTimeout=21600
```

I'm Using jTDS 1.3.1 and Hibernate 5.0.9 along with Spring Boot 1.4 to connect with SQL Server.

I'm running into following error while loading content from SQL Server

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Value 2009-02-25 07:51:54.2730000 +00:00 cannot be converted to TIMESTAMP.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Support.convert(Support.java:516) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.getTimestamp(JtdsResultSet.java:1182) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.getTimestamp(JtdsResultSet.java:1334) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
```

The value for that column and row in the database is `2009-02-25 07:51:54.273`

I'm probably missing something but I'm unable to figure it out even after some investigation. I tried with joda-time and jadira but exception didn't change. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Value 2009-02-25 07:51:54.2730000 +00:00 cannot be converted to TIMESTAMP.

Notice the timezone offset `+00:00` at the end of the date/time value. It indicates that the SQL Server column is almost certainly of the type `datetimeoffset`, not `datetime` as you stated in your question.

For more information on working with `datetimeoffset` values using jTDS, see the related question:

[using the datetimeoffset datatype with jTDS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36405320/2144390)